# Does restoring in-app purchases work with test accounts on iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Purchasing works perfect. But restoring in-app purchase doesn't work from test accounts on iTunes Connect. Is it correct? I use the following code to restore purchase:

```
... {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

// called when a transaction has been restored and and successfully completed
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    [self recordTransaction:transaction.originalTransaction];
    [self provideContent:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}

// saves a record of the transaction by storing the receipt to disk
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:[self getProductId:gFullVersion]]) {
        // save the transaction receipt to disk
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:[self getProductId:gFullVersion]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}

// removes the transaction from the queue and posts a notification with the transaction result
- (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:(BOOL)wasSuccessful {
    // remove the transaction from the payment queue.
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:transaction, @"transaction" , nil];
    if (wasSuccessful) {
        // send out a notification that we’ve finished the transaction
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    } else {
        // send out a notification for the failed transaction
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    }
}
```

The application shows dialog to enter AppleID password.

Comment: And what happens when you enter your Apple ID password?

Comment: Restoring should work fine in development with test accounts.

Comment: Nothing happens. Restoring doesn't work now. But it worked before with the same code.

Comment: It seems something wrong with App Store with test accounts. Restoring stops working on all devices with test accounts. Can anybody check it?

Comment: maybe you accidently tryed to use your test account outside the sandbox this invalidates the test-user and it does not work properly anymore. [test user](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html)

Comment: I've tried to use it with my application built by xcode. Tried many times.

Comment: What kind of in-app purchase are you trying to restore ?

Comment: It's non-consumable in-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I have two non-consumable in-apps. One is removed. And one is active. The following code returns only removed in-app:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

So, the issue is on App Store...

P.S. When I buy it again it's free, so two in-apps are really made.

Comment: Can you elaborate here a little bit. Are you saying that you cannot test restoring In-App Purchases with a sandbox account? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I followed this code for Restore button.

```
  -(void)restoreButtonTapped{

  [[RMStore defaultStore] restoreTransactionsOnSuccess:^{
                NSLog(@"Restored Successfully");
                [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
                [apDelegate hideLoading];
                BOOL isExpired = [self isPurchaseExpired:[NSDate date]]; // DEV-TODO: again fetching the expireDate from user Defaults in the method, so just sending the current Date.
                if (!isExpired)
                {
                    [self moveToLoginScreen];
                }
                else
                {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"Product expired, Please buy the product for uninterrupted services." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alert show];
                }
            } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
                NSLog(@"Failed to restore Completed Transactions");
                [apDelegate hideLoading];
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"MDPulse" message:@"Failed to restore Transactions. Please try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
            }];
        }


  }




   - (void)restoreCompletedTransactions
  {
    NSLog(@"Restore Tapped in transaction process");
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
  }

  - (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
  {
NSLog(@"Restore completed transactions finished.");
NSLog(@" Number of transactions in queue: %d", [[queue transactions] count]);
for (SKPaymentTransaction *trans in [queue transactions])
  {
    NSLog(@" transaction id %@ for product %@.", [trans transactionIdentifier], [[trans payment] productIdentifier]);
    NSLog(@" original transaction id: %@ for product %@.", [[trans originalTransaction] transactionIdentifier],
          [[[trans originalTransaction] payment]productIdentifier]);


    if ([[[trans payment] productIdentifier] isEqual: kMDPulseSubscriptionProductIdentifier]) {

        NSLog(@"Purchase Restored");

        // Do your stuff to unlock
    }
  }
  }

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"%s","User Cancel.");

MedPulseAppDelegate *appdelegate =( MedPulseAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[appdelegate hideLoading];

}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

[self validateReceiptForTransaction:transaction];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
 }
```

Welcome!

I think this will help you out.